# SeleniumRC - selenium.type function doesnt place my text in the field

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

I am trying to place some text in the search box of stackoverflow.com using this code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer;
import org.testng.Assert;

    import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
    import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;


    public class SeleniumRC {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444,"*firefox" ,"http://stackoverflow.com/");
        selenium.start(); //Launches the browser with a new Selenium session
        selenium.open("/"); //Opens an URL in the test frame.
        selenium.windowMaximize();//Resize currently selected window to take up the entire screen
        selenium.windowFocus();//Gives focus to the currently selected window
        selenium.getTitle();// Returns title of current page
        selenium.type(".//*[@id='search']/input", "justAtest"); //Sets the value of an input field, as though you typed it in.
```

In practice, the page open but no data placed in the search field and the "Ask Question button" isnt being clicked.

any idea what am i doing wrong??

*i installed firebug and firepath on my ubuntu 12.04 but when i run this code threw eclipse the browser open without any of the add-ons (if it helps)...

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why are you using Selenium RC? It has been deprecated several **years** ago.

Comment: Its one of the first chapters in selenium tutorial im working with...im not planning to use it in practice

Comment: Try this xpath for the search input: //form[@id='search']/input  ie: selenium.type("//form[@id='search']/input", "justAtest");